# Is there a way to get the AdSet/Ad info by using an fbclid?

Tags: facebook, ads

Basically, just want to know what AdSet/Ad a sale originated from by using the fbclid generated when a user clicks on a Facebook ad.

Comment: Do you find a way? I'm searching the same way to know which ads convert or not. Thanks.